# "Invariant Violation: Application AwesomeProject has not been registered" When building for iOS device with static jsbundle

Tags: ios, react-native

First off, I don't know react, but I figured deploying to an iOS device instead of the simulator wouldn't be too difficult to do with the docs. They were a bit sparse but I got somewhere and now I'm stuck.
I created a main.jsbundle and added it to the Xcode project and uncommented the line in AppDelegate.m.

When I deploy it I get this error:

```
2015-03-26 16:13:08.538 AwesomeProject[4753:2477032] >
  RCTJSLog> "Running application "AwesomeProject" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF"
2015-03-26 16:13:08.547 AwesomeProject[4753:2477032] >
  RCTJSLog> "Error: 
 stack: 
  runApplication                  main.jsbundle:33769
  jsCall                          main.jsbundle:7157
  _callFunction                   main.jsbundle:7404
  applyWithGuard                  main.jsbundle:877
  guardReturn                     main.jsbundle:7206
  callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue  main.jsbundle:7413
 URL: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DBC0DAF4-B568-4CF5-B156-9EFEE4E7FF4A/AwesomeProject.app/main.jsbundle
 line: 1536
 message: Invariant Violation: Application AwesomeProject has not been registered."
2015-03-26 16:13:08.723 AwesomeProject[4753:2477032] >
  RCTJSLog> "#CLOWNTOWN (error while displaying error): Network request failed"
```

Answer (score 145, accepted):

I'm pretty sure @krazyeom's fix has nothing to do with this error. In my case, I fixed this by quitting the terminal that was running from a previous test app I had run. It seems the terminal was confused and was still hooked to a process whose project was no longer loaded in XCode. Try the following:

1. Shut the Terminal spawned by React Native.
2. Shut down XCode completely (may not be necessary).
3. Re-open everything and re-run.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with restarting Xcode or Terminal.

Comment: I tried this too so I don't think it's this either.

Comment: This certainly fixed my issue, I too was running my second test React Native app when encountering this error message. On second reading I don't think it's the same issue you're having however...

Comment: i did not need to restart xcode. just shut down terminal, and run again.  had left terminal open from a different react native project

Comment: This did the trick for me (except for quitting Xcode). The very first build always takes too much time and that results in an error. Stopping and starting in Xcode is not sufficient at that point, the terminal must be stopped as well.

Comment: Quit terminal does the trick for me. Wasn't needed to restart XCode. Thanks :)

Comment: Killing the "terminal" (actually, the "Package manager") does the trick.  Restarting XCode is not necessary.

Comment: this worked for me. Not just for the 'Awesome' project but for any React Native project where you are bouncing between 2 projects

Comment: I didn't have to restart Xcode, but I did have to restart the iPhone Simulator

Comment: I hate 'solutions' like this. 1. It didn't work for me. 2. Even if it did, it doesn't explain why it worked.  It might as well say 'Go check your email, then come back and reload the Simulator'.

Comment: I was also bouncing between two projects (one to test on). My problem was that I was running "npm/yarn/react-native start" instead of "run ios". The latter builds the app, the former just runs metro and waits for an existing app to connect.

Answer (score 108):

Your problem shouldn't have anything to do with the console, if you properly bundled your javascript into the ios app it wont be trying to talk to dev server, it'll just get the javascript from the bundle.

From the error message I'd guess that you might have renamed your main component. Be sure that in your main `index.js` the `'AppName'` you pass into the

`AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppName' /* <- */, ... )`

matches with the `@"AppName"` on your `AppDelegate.m` on the call for

```
[[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleUrl:...
                            moduleName:@"AppName" // <-
                         launchOptions:...
```

Comment: You have to restart the package manager if you change the app you're running.

Comment: best explanation. the fact that the main component's name must match the module name you have in AppDelegate.m

Comment: Thank you very much! I renamed my project and was with this issue. Very nice to notice that. Now I have to discover what libs are using AsyncStorage and NetInfo the old way and my app is crashing, since I don`t use then directly.

Comment: Yes. After renaming the main component this error appeared. Changing the `AppName`, resolves the issue. Thank you

Comment: I had the same issue. After i found this answer, i check ios and android folders has files that refers to wrong moduleName. This occured after i merge with my old branch on my repository. So i deleted the old files and it works for me

Comment: This was exactly my issue (I missed the capital letter at the beginning of my app name). Thanks!

Answer (score 41):

I got this issue after renaming the project name and a couple of files. to solve it just make sure that the name of the app is the same in index.js app.json, MainActivity.java and AppDelegate.m.

**app.json**

```
{ "name": "MyNewApp", "displayName": "MyNewApp" }
```

**index.js**

`AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyNewApp', () => MyNewApp);`

**MainActivity.java**

```
`@Override protected String getMainComponentName() {
return "MyNewApp"; }
```

Comment: This one fixed my issue. The project I was given just had an android folder into it. I created a new project from scratch and copied the ios folder into the former project and because there was a mismatch in the names, it was failing to launch. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 33):

It is because the react-native server is still watching the old one.
You need to shut the server down first.

You could just kill the process.

In terminal

```
ps aux | grep react
```

Kill or pkill the process and then

```
npm start
```

Comment: This was my issue. Careful if you had started several projects! You need to realize that the react server may still be running in the background for the first project you started.  Once I killed the default 'awesomeproject', my new app started and ran fine.

Answer (score 25):

AppRegistry defines the entry point to the application and provides the root component.

Your first param doesn't match your project name.

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => YourMainComponent);
```

First param of `registerComponent` has to be your project name, second param is anonymous function that returns your root react component.

If first param doesn't match xcode project name, you get that error that your application has not been registered.

In case you don't have AppRegistry in the scope you can call it like this
`React.AppRegistry.registerComponent` or you can assign it to the `AppRegistry` var

```
var {
  AppRegistry
} = React;
```

Comment: This helped me when I was doing the [react-native tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html) after creating the project via their "Getting Started" `react-native init AwesomeProject` instruction.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue. I solved it by giving the same name to both **AppDelegate's moduleName** and **AppRegistry.registerComponent**

If you are running the app with `$ react-native run-ios` you will need to rename  the `moduleName` field in `./ios/[project name]/AppDelegate.m` to match the new name of the project. Refresh the phone simulator and it should show the new code.

Comment: Agreed, the other answers didn't help me, I added some more detailed info about how to fix it

Comment: It's case sensitive!

Answer (score 17):

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('abc',() => ***);
```

the `'abc'` must be the same as the `moduleName:@'abc'` in the file name `AppDelegate.m`

Comment: I accidentally messed this up. Your answer solved i for me, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Did you change the name of the app that you're registering?  I started the app with the name 'tricky', then later changed the name in this line:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyNewApp', () => MyNewApp);
```

and I started getting the invariant error.

Comment: In that case change the target name as well, or hard code the new name in Info.plist.

Answer (score 5):

Check the app's name in the `app.json` file in the project's root directory.

This name should be the same as in the `AppDelegate.m` file.

Comment: This is the write answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot later, but I was still experiencing this same issue. I tried to follow the restart everything path but it didn't fix it. 
What ended up fixing this for me was making sure my app.json 'name' field (used the same value in the 'displayName' field) matched the 'moduleName' field in my RCTRootView. 
matched those up and everything was groovy. 
Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

I am not fan of closing down everything so I dig this further.

All I had to do is in my terminal window, I ran this command:

```
../lala/node_modules/react-native/packager/launchPackager.command ; exit;
```

My project name was "lala" , so find that there is node_modules in your project too.

replace lala with your project name it should work.

If there is an error says port is already in use:

```
 ERROR  Packager can't listen on port 8081
```

Then you have two choices:

- Kill already running program.
- Or Change the port by going into : `../lala/node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.js` then find your port number, example 8081, and replace with the port number that is not in use.

> ```
>  var options = parseCommandLine([{
>           command: 'port',
>           default: 8082,
>         }, {
> ```

Save this file and then run the above command again.

This way I can run multiple react(ors).

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error, restarting everything including the xcode and terminal worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Reference a nameless person.

it works for me.

---

I had almost the same problem you currently have a few days ago. For me it was a real device.

From all my research, the solution that worked for me is the following:

1. When you launch your app by typing react-native run-android, the
   error appears.
2. So, reach your directory containing "adb.exe" ( for me it was
   `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\` )
3. open a terminal from here. And type adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
4. Then, by reloading the app on the phone, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this `Error` nowadays has to do with the different versions of `react-navigation` being used.

If you are using react-navigation 4.0

`"react-navigation": "^4.1.0",`

you have to make sure you are importing the right elements from the right places

in your `app.js`

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs'
```

This has helped me resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar message in the console.

message: Invariant Violation: Application AwesomeProject has not been registered."

I just added `REACT_EDITOR=atom` on ~/.bashrc file.