# How to use node modules with React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I'm new to React Native and would like to use a node module inside the React Native app I'm playing around with.

The node module I would like to add is this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/swisseph

So I went inside the project folder and ran `npm install swisseph`

In the app source code I added this:

```
var swisseph = require ('swisseph');
```

I ran the project and I get this error:

```
Invariant Violation: Application AwesomeProject has not been registered.
This is either due to a require() error during initialisation or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent.
```

How does one use node modules inside React Native?

The index.io.js file has these code:

```
    /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var swisseph = require ('swisseph');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

var AwesomeProject = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Comment: What's your `index.ios.js` look like?

Comment: Hi, I added the code inside index.ios.js above...thank you...

Comment: It says AwesomeProject not swisseph so the particular error might be not be caused by the newly added module. 

try solution presented here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287987/invariant-violation-application-awesomeproject-has-not-been-registered-when-b

this worked for me when i encountered the `has not been registered` error.

Answer (score 1):

I would try running this with chrome debugger on. There might be some problem that is causing your JS to crash before you get to:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

To open chrome debugging hit command+d and then click on Debug in Chrome. This should open chrome with instructions on how to see the console output.

Comment: Hi, yes...it is the var swisseph = require ('swisseph');
that is causing it to crash.  That is the node module I would like to add to my project.  How do I add it properly?

Comment: After looking at swisseph, you might be out of luck. It looks as though as part of it's installation it uses "node-gyp rebuilt" to compile C++ code for it's JavaScript to use. React-Native unfortunately doesn't run a nodejs server on your iPhone and so you really don't have access to all the glory which is nodejs. Your app is crashing because it can't find the necessary native bindings. One option you do have is to add the swisseph C++ code to your project making sure to expose the necessary binding for React-Native to use. See http://moduscreate.com/react_native_custom_components_ios/