# React Native - ios - loading from pre-budled file fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, react-native

I have a react native app that works fine with the dev server.

I want to bundle the app to be served locally from within the xcode project. So, I started the dev server and ran

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true' -o ios/main.jsbundle
```

this created a new file inside my ios folder called main.jsbundle. I then went to my `AppDelegate.m` and changed my `jsCodeLocation` to

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

everything seems right, but when I build the project from `xcode` I see `Loading from bundled file ...` at the top of the emulator and not nothing else.

From the chrome debugger I see

```
    Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 
'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 
'file:///Users/benconant/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3054F999-82…281E-90D6-410D-BC17-
81A6D1DFCA2A/Eastern%20Car%20Service.app/main.jsbundle' failed to 
load.messageHandlers.executeApplicationScript @ 
debuggerWorker.js:18onmessage @ debuggerWorker.js:42
```

If I click on the file path it takes me to the bundle with all the javascript code for my app. Not sure why this bundle is not able to load ... it seems like it is the same bundle as is sent from the server when

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

just FYI ... I have also tried following the official steps for creating a bundle that are found at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#content this led to the same exact error. My thought was that if the bundle was loading from my dev server I should make sure that the one i am putting into my project is identical to that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok ... so after a few hours of digging and playing around I solved this problem. First I needed to disable the chrome debugging feature `command + option + z` This was what was causing the the

```
Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 
'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 
'file:///Users/benconant/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3054F999-82…281E-90D6-410D-BC17-
81A6D1DFCA2A/Eastern%20Car%20Service.app/main.jsbundle' failed to 
load.messageHandlers.executeApplicationScript @ 
debuggerWorker.js:18onmessage @ debuggerWorker.js:42
```

then I got the error described in this post ["Invariant Violation: Application AwesomeProject has not been registered" When building for iOS device with static jsbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287987/invariant-violation-application-awesomeproject-has-not-been-registered-when-b) ... 
I ended up renaming my app from App to a more appropriate name in both `AppDelegate.m` and my root component. And boom ... it worked. I think the big take away is to ensure that chrome debugger is disabled when trying to load from a bundle.

Comment: I'm having this same issue except that I'd like to run the debugger to do some debugging.  Do you know how to run the debugger without the "Loading from bundled file" staying at the top of the page (and the rest of the app not loading)?

Comment: Same issue as @Brad. Any solution?