# Issues with upgrading to React Native 0.26

Tags: react-native

I'm in a bind , I don't know how to debug this issue as the app fails before the debugger is available.

[image]

It all started when I tried to upgrade to React Native 0.26 ( upgrading to 0.29 would be a huge change set to for our codebase, so doing this in multiple steps).

I have followed the documentation to import `Component` from `react` and the rest from `react-native`

I have updated to the latest dependencies or atleast as far as the modules support 0.26

However I'm seeing the `Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module.` and I cannot attach a debugger (I hope I'm mistaken here). I have searched the code base and there are no components that use `AppRegistry`.

Here's the package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyProjectName",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "code-push": "^1.8.0-beta",
    "dateformat": "^1.0.12",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "key-mirror": "^1.0.1",
    "numeral": "^1.5.3",
    "react": "15.0.2",
    "react-addons-update": "15.0.2",
    "react-mixin": "^3.0.3",
    "react-native": "^0.26.3",
    "react-native-code-push": "^1.10.0-beta",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-custom-action-sheet": "0.0.11",
    "react-native-datetime": "0.1.2",
    "react-native-dismiss-keyboard": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.2.6",
    "react-native-fabric": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-picker-android": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-tab-navigator": "^0.3.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.0",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.3",
    "realm": "^0.14.1",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "validator": "^5.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Here's the `index.ios.js` (the android version is also the exact same thing)

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Navigator,
} from 'react-native';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './lib/store/configureStore';

import App from './lib/app';

class MyProjectName extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        let store = configureStore({});
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <App {...this.props}/>
            </Provider>
        );
    }

    componentWillMount() {

    }

    componentDidMount(){
       // const CodePush = require('react-native-code-push');
        // wait for 3 seconds otherwise rollback this change
       // CodePush.sync({ rollbackTimeout: 3000 });
    }

}

module.exports = MyProjectName;
```

Any hints on how to solve this ?

Comment: can you show your `index.js` file contents?

Comment: I have updated the question with content of `index.ios.js`

Comment: is this relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30427137/1206613

Comment: @Cherniv thank you! For some reason I assumed `AppRegistry` was deprecated in 0.26

Answer (score 0):

I got this message when a module in `node_modules` was still requiring `React` from `react-native`.

I would suggest going through all of your react native modules and looking for the ones which still use:

```
var React = require('react-native');
```

and replace them with:

```
import React from 'react';
```

And similarly import react native modules from `react-native`