# Application main thread has not been registered in react native

Tags: android, react-native

Hi I am new in react native programming, I am trying to make first program in it. I am facing below issue :-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
```

[image]

[image]

### Edit

I am using this tool https://rnplay.org

Comment: I dont see any problem with your code.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287987/invariant-violation-application-awesomeproject-has-not-been-registered-when-b ?

Comment: @Jickson I have already checked that question before asking this. I am using this tool https://rnplay.org not sure what is creating an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using rnplay, You need to call

```
registerComponent(HelloWorldApp);
```

instead of

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
```

Sample Hello world example

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  registerComponent,
} from 'react-native-playground';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

class HelloWorldApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
         Hello world
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  instructions: {
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 15,
  },
});

registerComponent(HelloWorldApp);
```