# react-native error "application appname has not ben registered" onsublime text

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new in react native programming, I am trying to make this work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

class AppName extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
   }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppName', () => AppName);
```

but I am facing below issue : application appname has not been registered 
i tried the following solution but its not working for me  [Application main thread has not been registered in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40285368/application-main-thread-has-not-been-registered-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `'AppName'` on the last line is not the same as what you named your project on creation. It should be the same name as your project directory. Capitalization matters. Looking at your error message, you named your project `appname`.

For example if you create a project:

```
react-native init appname
```

And if your class is still the same name:

```
class AppName extends Component {
```

Your last line should be:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('appname', () => AppName);
```